# App is crashing when floating action button is clicked

Tags: android, fragment

I am using floating action button for navigation from one activity to another but when i am clicking then app is crashing, there is no problem in floating action button, problem is in another activity where its been navigated. And its been navigated to uploadPost class.

```
   public class uploadPost extends Fragment implements SelectPhotoDialog.OnPhotoSelectedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "uploadPost";

    @Override
    public void getImagePath(Uri imagePath) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getImagePath: setting the image to imageview");
        UniversalImageLoader.setImage(imagePath.toString(), mPostImage);
        //assign to global variable
        mSelectedBitmap = null;
        mSelectedUri = imagePath;
    }

    @Override
    public void getImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getImageBitmap: setting the image to imageview");
        mPostImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        //assign to a global variable
        mSelectedUri = null;
        mSelectedBitmap = bitmap;
    }

    //widgets
    private ImageView mPostImage;
    private EditText mTitle, mDescription, mPrice, mCountry, mStateProvince, mCity, mContactEmail,mCollege;
    private Button mPost;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    //vars
    private Bitmap mSelectedBitmap;
    private Uri mSelectedUri;
    private byte[] mUploadBytes;
    private double mProgress = 0;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_upload_post, container, false);
        mPostImage = view.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        mTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.input_title);
        mDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.input_description);
        mPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.input_price);
        mCountry = view.findViewById(R.id.input_country);
        mStateProvince = view.findViewById(R.id.input_state_province);
        mCity = view.findViewById(R.id.input_city);
        mContactEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        mCollege = view.findViewById(R.id.input_clg);
        mPost = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_post);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        mCountry.setText("India");
        mStateProvince.setText("Maharashtra");
        mCity.setText("Pune");

        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

        init();

        return view;
    }

    private void init(){

        mPostImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: opening dialog to choose new photo");
                SelectPhotoDialog dialog = new SelectPhotoDialog();
                dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), getString(R.string.dialog_select_photo));
                dialog.setTargetFragment(uploadPost.this, 1);
            }
        });

        mPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: attempting to post...");
                if(!isEmpty(mTitle.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(mDescription.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(mPrice.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(mCountry.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(mStateProvince.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(mCity.getText().toString())
                        && !isEmpty(mContactEmail.getText().toString())){

                    //we have a bitmap and no Uri
                    if(mSelectedBitmap != null && mSelectedUri == null){
                        uploadNewPhoto(mSelectedBitmap);
                    }
                    //we have no bitmap and a uri
                    else if(mSelectedBitmap == null && mSelectedUri != null){
                        uploadNewPhoto(mSelectedUri);
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You must fill out all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void uploadNewPhoto(Bitmap bitmap){
        Log.d(TAG, "uploadNewPhoto: uploading a new image bitmap to storage");
        BackgroundImageResize resize = new BackgroundImageResize(bitmap);
        Uri uri = null;
        resize.execute(uri);
    }

    private void uploadNewPhoto(Uri imagePath){
        Log.d(TAG, "uploadNewPhoto: uploading a new image uri to storage.");
        BackgroundImageResize resize = new BackgroundImageResize(null);
        resize.execute(imagePath);
    }

    public class BackgroundImageResize extends AsyncTask<Uri, Integer, byte[]>{

        Bitmap mBitmap;

        public BackgroundImageResize(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if(bitmap != null){
                this.mBitmap = bitmap;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "compressing image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            showProgressBar();
        }

        @Override
        protected byte[] doInBackground(Uri... params) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: started.");

            if(mBitmap == null){
                try{
                    RotateBitmap rotateBitmap = new RotateBitmap();
                    mBitmap = rotateBitmap.HandleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(getActivity(), params[0]);
                }catch (IOException e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            byte[] bytes = null;
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: megabytes before compression: " + mBitmap.getByteCount() / 1000000 );
            bytes = getBytesFromBitmap(mBitmap, 100);
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: megabytes before compression: " + bytes.length / 1000000 );
            return bytes;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(byte[] bytes) {
            super.onPostExecute(bytes);
            mUploadBytes = bytes;
            hideProgressBar();
            //execute the upload task
            executeUploadTask();
        }
    }

    private void executeUploadTask(){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "uploading image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final String postId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().getKey();

        final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("posts/users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() +
                        "/" + postId + "/post_image");

        UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putBytes(mUploadBytes);
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Post Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //insert the download url into the firebase database
                Uri firebaseUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: firebase download url: " + firebaseUri.toString());
                DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                Post post = new Post();
                post.setImage(firebaseUri.toString());
                post.setCity(mCity.getText().toString());
                post.setContact_email(mContactEmail.getText().toString());
                post.setCountry(mCountry.getText().toString());
                post.setDescription(mDescription.getText().toString());
                post.setPost_id(postId);
                post.setPrice(mPrice.getText().toString());
                post.setState_province(mStateProvince.getText().toString());
                post.setTitle(mTitle.getText().toString());
                post.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                post.setCollege(mCollege.getText().toString());

                reference.child(getString(R.string.node_posts))
                        .child(postId)
                        .setValue(post);

                resetFields();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "could not upload photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double currentProgress = (100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                if( currentProgress > (mProgress + 15)){
                    mProgress = (100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onProgress: upload is " + mProgress + "& done");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mProgress + "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int quality){
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality,stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }


    private void resetFields(){
        UniversalImageLoader.setImage("", mPostImage);
        mTitle.setText("");
        mDescription.setText("");
        mPrice.setText("");
        mCountry.setText("India");
        mStateProvince.setText("Maharashtra");
        mCity.setText("Pune");
        mContactEmail.setText("");
        mCollege.setText("");
    }

    private void showProgressBar(){
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void hideProgressBar(){
        if(mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return true if the @param is null
     * @param string
     * @return
     */
    private boolean isEmpty(String string){
        return string.equals("");
    }
}
```

And it is been navigated from SearchActivity class

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private static final String TAG = "SearchActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

    //widgets
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;
    public ViewPager mViewPager;

    //vars
    public SectionsPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    //navigation drawer
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

    //user info
    TextView uname,uemail;
    String pemail,pname;
    ImageView pimage;
    CoordinatorLayout navigation;

    FloatingActionButton fab;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);



        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mViewPager  = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_container);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        navigation = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.error);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close)
        {
            /* Called when a drawer has settled in a completely close state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
               // fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               //navigation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
              // fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                // navigation.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        };
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.red4)));

        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        pimage = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.pimage);
        uname = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.uname);
        uemail = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.emailo);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SearchActivity.this);
        pemail = sharedPref.getString("email", "Not Available");
        pname = sharedPref.getString("username", "Not Available");

        uname.setText(pname);
        uemail.setText(pemail);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,uploadPost.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        setupFirebaseListener();
        verifyPermissions();

    }


    private void setupFirebaseListener() {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupFirebaseListener: setting up the auth state listener.");
        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged: signed_in: " + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged: signed_out");
                    Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Signed out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthStateListener != null) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(){
        mPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPagerAdapter.addFragment(new SearchFragment());
        mPagerAdapter.addFragment(new WatchListFragment());
       // mPagerAdapter.addFragment(new PostFragment());

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText(getString(R.string.fragment_search));
        mTabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText(getString(R.string.fragment_watch_list));
       // mTabLayout.getTabAt(2).setText(getString(R.string.fragment_post));
    }

    private void verifyPermissions(){
        Log.d(TAG, "verifyPermissions: asking user for permissions");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                permissions[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                permissions[2]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            setupViewPager();
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SearchActivity.this,
                    permissions,
                    REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        verifyPermissions();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.profile){

            Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,test.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Profile",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        if(id == R.id.aboutus){

            Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,Aboutus.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            Toast.makeText(this,"About Us",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        if(id == R.id.mypost){

            Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,MyPosts.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            Toast.makeText(this,"My Post",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        if(id == R.id.logout){

            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: attempting to sign out the user.");
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

        }


        return false;

    }
}
```

I am not able to understand the error which i am seeing on my logs

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: codingwithmitch.com.forsale, PID: 13518
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{codingwithmitch.com.forsale/codingwithmitch.com.forsale.uploadPost}: java.lang.ClassCastException: codingwithmitch.com.forsale.uploadPost cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2561)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: codingwithmitch.com.forsale.uploadPost cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1100)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2551)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
```

my SearchActivity xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/error"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_black_24dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            fab:layout_editor_absoluteX="342dp"
            fab:layout_editor_absoluteY="458dp">

        </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Please show how you start the other Activity when the Button is clicked

Comment: You want to see the code?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: The logcat shows that you have a ClassCastException where you are trying to operate on `uploadPost` as if it is an `Activity`. It's not an `Activity` and therefore crashes when the operation is done on it.

Comment: I have updated my question, do have a look

Comment: @Bryan Dormaier is right, you can't say "startActivity()" and use it on a Fragment. Your uploadPost class extends from Fragment not from Activity. ( BTW class names in Java should begin with an uppercase letter)

Comment: `codingwithmitch.com.forsale.uploadPost cannot be cast to android.app.Activity` What exactly is confusing you about this?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error :

> cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

because you are trying to load `uploadPost` as an `Activity` but it extends `Fragment` so you get the "cannot be cast to android.app.Activity" error.

You must decide whether you want to load it as a `Fragment` or an `Activity`. If you want to load `uploadPost` as an `Activity` you need to extend to an `Activity` not `Fragment`

**EDIT**

If you wish to continue to use it as a `Fragment` you must use a `FragmentTransaction` to either `add()` the `Fragment` or `replace()` a `Fragment` in your activity layout.

You can replace a `Fragment` like this example:

```
Fragment fragment = new UploadPost();
if(fragment != null) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    //If you want to play around with different transaction animations 
    //fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment, "0");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Where `R.id.content_main` is just a `RelativeLayout` in my MainActivity which is replaced by the `uploadPost` fragment.

And as 0X0nosugar indicated: It is java naming convention to capitalize class names. Please adopt this convention--otherwise you will make it more difficult to understand your code.

**EDIT 2**

Often a `Fragment` will be used to swap views in an container `Activity`. For example I use them to swap views in combination with a `DrawerLayout`. In this case I will continue to replace fragments, but never really remove one explicitly.

For example I will have a xml layout file very similar to your "SearchActivity" file. Just below the `</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>` tag I will introduce a `RelativeLayout` with the id `android:id="@+id/content_main"`. This `RelativeLayout` is just a dummy container view and is being replaced with whatever is in my selected `Fragment`. So you would need to change the `onClick` code to replace the fragment as I showed above.

With another action you might want to either remove that fragment or replace it with another... that all depends on your app design--which I do not know.

Comment: I have to load it as a fragment only, for doing this what exactly i have to do

Comment: @VishalSharma :: I have edited the answer. If you need more information to implement this please edit your question and provide the xml layout for the `SearchActivity` --- If that is where you wish to display the `Fragment`

Comment: I have attached my xml layout of SearchActivity, do have a look

Comment: @VishalSharma :: I hope the information I provided in "Edit 2" helps you. Without in-depth information about your app more guidance will be difficult